# MySQL Returning 'ずる' When Searching for 'する' (Japanese)

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have a database with Japanese words. I'm stumped because this query:

```
SELECT japanese
FROM my_table
where japanese = 'する'
```

returns two results:

```
ずる
する
```

I tried to look in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/faqs-cjk.html) but can't figure out what's going on or how to correct it. Here's some of the information about my setup using the queries recommended in the documentation:

```
 SELECT CHARACTER_SET_NAME, DESCRIPTION
       FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CHARACTER_SETS
       WHERE DESCRIPTION LIKE '%Japanese%'
       ORDER BY CHARACTER_SET_NAME;
```

Returns:

```
'CHARACTER_SET_NAME','DESCRIPTION' 
'cp932', 'SJIS for Windows Japanese'
'eucjpms', 'UJIS for Windows Japanese'
'sjis', 'Shift-JIS Japanese'
'ujis', 'EUC-JP Japanese'
```

And the following query:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%'
```

Returns:

```
character_set_client    utf8mb4
character_set_connection    utf8mb4
character_set_database  utf8mb4
character_set_filesystem    binary
character_set_results   utf8mb4
character_set_server    utf8mb4
character_set_system    utf8
```

And this really gets beyond my skill set. If someone can point me in the right direction that would be a big help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use accent sensitive collation:

```
SELECT japanese
FROM my_table
where japanese = 'する' COLLATE  utf8mb4_ja_0900_as_cs;
-- alternatively binary collation: COLLATE  utf8mb4_bin
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f5c4521d70a3af864482d26de7f33a54)**

---

> [Introducing as_cs collations](https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-1-accent-and-case-sensitive-collations-for-utf8mb4/):
>
> In MySQL 8.0.0 we improved our character set support with the addition of new accent and case insensitive (ai_ci) collations.  **In MySQL 8.0.1 the corresponding accent and case sensitive collations (as_cs) have also been added, as well as a Japanese collation**

Comment: @SDS keep in mind that `COLLATE` keyword is also valid in [table structures](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html)..  part of the BNF `| data_type
      [COLLATE collation_name]` of `column_definition:` .. Also meaning you can [ALTER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html) the `COLLATE` aswell